# fuseki .NullPointerException

Tags: java, jena, owl, fuseki

I have a small data, which I uploaded for you on this link

http://www.mediafire.com/download/0bv89wfc65a50sl/data.ttl

and when I apply the query that I uploaded for you on this link

http://www.mediafire.com/download/bjz4zpnj0220szz/query.sparql

Fuseki throws this exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.binding.BindingBase.hashCode(BindingBase.java:203)
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.binding.BindingBase.hashCode(BindingBase.java:183)
    at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:338)
    at java.util.HashMap.containsKey(HashMap.java:595)
    at java.util.HashSet.contains(HashSet.java:203)
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.iterator.QueryIterDistinct.getInputNextUnseen(QueryIterDistinct.java:106)
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.iterator.QueryIterDistinct.hasNextBinding(QueryIterDistinct.java:70)
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.iterator.QueryIteratorBase.hasNext(QueryIteratorBase.java:111)
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.iterator.QueryIteratorWrapper.hasNextBinding(QueryIteratorWrapper.java:39)
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.iterator.QueryIteratorBase.hasNext(QueryIteratorBase.java:111)
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.iterator.QueryIteratorWrapper.hasNextBinding(QueryIteratorWrapper.java:39)
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.iterator.QueryIteratorBase.hasNext(QueryIteratorBase.java:111)
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.ResultSetStream.hasNext(ResultSetStream.java:74)
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.ResultSetCheckCondition.hasNext(ResultSetCheckCondition.java:59)
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.resultset.ResultSetApply.apply(ResultSetApply.java:38)
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.resultset.JSONOutput.format(JSONOutput.java:34)
    at org.apache.jena.query.ResultSetFormatter.outputAsJSON(ResultSetFormatter.java:500)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.servlets.ResponseResultSet$2.output(ResponseResultSet.java:211)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.servlets.ResponseResultSet.output(ResponseResultSet.java:303)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.servlets.ResponseResultSet.jsonOutput(ResponseResultSet.java:229)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.servlets.ResponseResultSet.doResponseResultSet$(ResponseResultSet.java:149)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.servlets.ResponseResultSet.doResponseResultSet(ResponseResultSet.java:93)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.servlets.SPARQL_Query.sendResults(SPARQL_Query.java:396)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.servlets.SPARQL_Query.execute(SPARQL_Query.java:272)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.servlets.SPARQL_Query.executeWithParameter(SPARQL_Query.java:228)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.servlets.SPARQL_Query.perform(SPARQL_Query.java:213)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.servlets.ActionSPARQL.executeLifecycle(ActionSPARQL.java:134)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.servlets.SPARQL_UberServlet.executeRequest(SPARQL_UberServlet.java:354)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.servlets.SPARQL_UberServlet.serviceDispatch(SPARQL_UberServlet.java:315)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.servlets.SPARQL_UberServlet.executeAction(SPARQL_UberServlet.java:271)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.servlets.ActionSPARQL.execCommonWorker(ActionSPARQL.java:85)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.servlets.ActionBase.doCommon(ActionBase.java:81)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.servlets.FusekiFilter.doFilter(FusekiFilter.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:285)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1156)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1088)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2016-05-18 10:20:00] Fuseki     INFO  [11] 500 Server Error (186 ms)
r
```

I am working with fuseki apache-jena-fuseki-2.4.0

You just need to upload the data to fuseki and run the query to get the exception.

#### Update

I was able to reduce the query and still get the same error

```
SELECT  distinct ?item ?itemClass ?userContext ?skip ?userContextWeight ?reason ((?similarity * ?importance * ?levelImportance * ?ratingValue) as ?finalSimilarity) ?userClass 
WHERE
  { 

  { 

    VALUES ?user { bo:ania }
    values ?item {:exampleBook}
    } 
  #
    OPTIONAL
      { 
   #  VALUES ?user { rs:Issac_Newton }

        ?userContext  rdf:type       rs:UserContext ;
                  rs:appliedOnItems  ?itemClass ;
                  rs:appliedOnUsers  ?userClass .

    OPTIONAL
          { ?userContext  rs:hasWeightIfContextMatched  ?weightMatched }
        OPTIONAL
          { ?userContext  rs:hasWeightIfContextDoesNotMatch  ?weightNotMatched }
        OPTIONAL
          { ?userContext  rs:doNotRecommendInCaseNotMatch  true
            BIND(1 AS ?skip_)
          }
      }
 VALUES ?user { bo:ania }
    bind(if (bound(?skip_) && (not EXISTS {?user a ?userClass}) && (EXISTS {?item a ?itemClass}) , ?skip_, 0) as ?skip1)

    values (?defaultUserMatched ?defaultUserNotMatched) {(1 0.5)}
        BIND(if(EXISTS { ?user  rdf:type  ?userClass }, coalesce(?weightMatched, ?defaultUserMatched), coalesce(?weightNotMatched, ?defaultUserNotMatched)) AS ?weight)

  bind (if ( exists {?item  a  ?itemClass }, true , false) as ?doesItemBelongToUserContextItemClass)

    values ?defaultNoUserContext {1}
    BIND(if(bound(?skip1), ?skip1, 0) as ?skip)

  BIND( if ( !?doesItemBelongToUserContextItemClass   , ?defaultNoUserContext ,if(bound(?weight), ?weight, ?defaultNoUserContext)) AS ?userContextWeight)
```

}

Comment: I don't know what the issue is exactly, but it looks like it's happening in [BindingBase.hashCode(Binding)](https://github.com/apache/jena/blob/master/jena-arq/src/main/java/org/apache/jena/sparql/engine/binding/BindingBase.java#L194).  If those line numbers match up, it looks like `node` must have been null.  If a binding doesn't have to provide a non-null value for each of its variables, that seems possible.  A fix might be to use `Objects.hashCode(node)` rather than `node.hashCode()`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor so shall i submit a ticket to fuseki? i alrady asked on the mailing list, though

Comment: You asked the same question on the Jena mailing list and Andy Seaborne already replied. So may I ask, why you ask this question here too?

Comment: The example runs just fine though this is not a compete, minimal, verified example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Start by creating a clean server, then cut the query down to something smaller.

Comment: For anyone coming in later, like me, I had the same trouble on v2.4.0 but upgrading to v3.4.0 solved it.